# Maven install/compile Failure

Tags: maven-2

I am getting below exception , When i compile/install through maven in command prompt / eclipse.

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ dashboard ---
May 22, 2013 3:55:50 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warnWARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFiltering
Exception
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1855)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.
java:245)


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.050s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 22 15:55:50 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project dashboard: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
```

I have tried by changing the repository location and  also  deleting the existing plugins in the repository directory.

Comment: Please provide further information and a more meaningful title to draw attention :)

Comment: Try build on command line first and post the output in case of an error.

Comment: The output i copied is from command line.

Comment: Try to delete the path in your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins` and retry that on command line check if you have warnings during the build about not downloaded pom files (dependencies) like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try if another task locks the maven-filtering jar file (`.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.xx/maven-filtering-1.xx.jar`). In my case Eclipse had locked that file somehow. Kill that task and maven should be ok.

Comment: Thanks I had both my eclipse and Intellij opened, same error was coming in Intellij. I closed my eclipse then error in Intellij got resolved.